# Svelte derived stores and array sort

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-store

I set up a store containing a list of rides loaded from my API:

```js
const loadRides = () => client.service('rides').find({
  query: {
    $sort: {
      date: -1,
    }
  }
});

const createRides = () => {
  const { subscribe, update } = writable([], async (set) => {
    try {
      const rides = await loadRides().then((result) => result.data);
      set(rides);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
    // Socket update binding?
  });

  subscribe((rides) => console.debug('rides', rides));

  return {
    subscribe,
    refresh: () => loadRides().then((result) => update(() => result.data)),
  };
};
export const rides = createRides();
```

Then I set a two derived stores for past and future rides:

```js
export const pastRides = derived(
  rides,
  ($rides) => $rides
    .filter((ride) => ride.steps.every((step) => step.doneAt))
  ,
);
export const comingRides = derived(
  rides,
  ($rides) => $rides
    .filter((ride) => ride.steps.some((step) => !step.doneAt))
    .sort((rideA, rideB) => {
      const compare = new Date(rideA.date) - new Date(rideB.date);
      console.log(rideA.date, rideB.date, compare);
      return compare;
    })
  ,
);
```

The `sort` method on the second one does not have any effect.

So I tried to put this method before the `filter` one. It works, but it also sort `$pastRides`. In fact, it is sorting the full `$rides` array and it make sens.

But I does not understand why the `sort` after `filter` does not work.

What did I miss?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing a minimal reproducible example, but might it have to to with `sort` mutating the array? You could try `$rides.slice()` to create a shallow copy of the array before you do anything else in the derivations to see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.sort` is mutable. Meaning, when you call `rides.sort`, it will sort and modify `rides` and return the sorted `rides`.

When you use `derived(rides, ($rides) => ... )`, the `$rides` you received is the original `rides` array that you call `set(rides)`. So you can imagine that both the `pastRides` and `comingRides` received the same `$rides` array.

you can observe this behavior in [this repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/44f170d0cd43440ca8dd8e2bff341bda?version=3.17.1)

To not having both `derived` interfere with each other, you can create a new array and sort the new array:

```js
const sorted_1 = derived(array, $a => [...$a].sort());
```

you can try this out in [this repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/af62e5bcfcda4ee0af905608d0213dc4?version=3.17.1).